# How to create sql function thats asks to input user id and to give output total friends?

Tags: sql, function, mysql-workbench

```
drop function if exists counting_friends;
delimiter //
create function counting_friends(id int)
returns int
begin
declare userCount int;
SELECT COUNT(*) as number_of_friends
from user_friend where source_id = id;
return (userCount);
end //
delimiter ;
# check the screenshot
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, need to make the select query populate the variable in the function:

Change the function's query from:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as number_of_friends
FROM user_friend WHERE source_id = id;
```

To:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO userCount 
FROM user_friend WHERE source_id = id;
```

Then you should be able to do:

```
SELECT counting_friends(2) AS Friends; -- or however you prefer to use the function call.
```

Example [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3cd3d2a9a451ad60d205e5336f53c7fc). (Note that at the site, I did not need to use delimiter, but this will be needed locally when you create the function, as you already have it now)